# Debug user movement on store to reproduce error on local environment?

Tags: commerce-cloud, debug, lwr

I am in a situation where I am encountering an error on my sandbox environment, I know how to trigger it, but I don't know what is throwing that error.

Is possible to somehow log everything from when a user enters a page, to the error message appears in salesforce b2b commerce cloud?

In my case this happens on a LWR checkout page.